# Adding ng-mouseover to <option>

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, mouseevent, html-select

I want to add mouseover event to every option and make an ajax call and dynamically add few more options as a sub options to that option.

How can I achieve this ?

```
<select>
    <option ng-mouseover="someFunction()"></option>
</select>
```

This isn't working for me. that 'someFunction' on scope is not getting called. Is the ng-mouseover not wokring or you can't add events to option tag ?

Comment: Perhaps you can take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32966436/tooltip-on-hover-of-select-box-options-generated-by-ng-options-in-angulerjs/32992391